# laravel relationship many to many

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I have relationship many to many:

---

Invoice.php

```
class Invoice extends Model {
     public function items() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'invoice_item', 'invoice_id', 
       'item_id')->withPivot('quantity'); 
}
```

---

Item.php

```
class Item extends Model {
 public function invoices() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Invoice' ,'invoice_item', 'item_id', 'invoice_id');
   }
```

---

```
class Invoice_item extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'quantity',
    ];
}
```

---

listInvoice.blade.php

```
 @foreach($invoice->items as $item)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $item->pivot->quantity}}</td>
</tr>
  @endforeach
```

---

problem is that when I try to display the quantity, 0 always appears :( Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have two Invoice classes. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes, should be Invoice_item in last file php ;)

Comment: I mean the class name: `class Invoice extends Model`

Comment: Aa ok, sorry it's typo, corrected

Comment: I don't know if this will solve the problem, but try to change the name of the class to: `InvoiceItem`, and add this line after `$fillable` variable: `protected $table = 'invoice_item';`

Comment: Unfortunately, all the time the quantity is 0 in blade.php

Comment: I had this issue recently and it was due to a very silly bug. In my case, quantity was already an attribute set up on my model, so that took precedence over the relationship; if this is the case, you could look at customising the pivot name (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

*I assume you are using Laravel 5.5 (as it is not mentioned)*

As already mentioned by [Laerte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967345/laerte), use `InvoiceItem` instead of `Invoice_item`.

And your Custom Intermediate Model must extend from `Pivot`; not from `Model`:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;    

class InvoiceItem extends Pivot 
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'quantity',
    ]; 
}
```

Comment: also an intermediate class won't be called unless being set by `using` on subjective class